# NSXMLParser in iPad XCode

Tags: objective-c, xml, xcode, nsxmlparser

I'm trying to get hold of data from a NSXMLParser

I have the following XML Sample Data:

```
<myCourse>
    <courseName>BEng Mobile and Web Computing</courseName>
    <courseStructure>
        <level4>
            <module>
                <moduleCode>ECSC401</moduleCode>
                <moduleTitle>Programming Methodology</moduleTitle>
                <credits>15</credits>
                <semester>1</semester>
                <assessmentDetails>
                    <assessment>
                        <assessmentName>Test1</assessmentName>
                        <assessmentType>Coursework</assessmentType>
                        <assessmentWeighting>30</assessmentWeighting>
                        <assessmentDueDate/>
                    </assessment>
                    <assessment>
                        <assessmentName>Coursework</assessmentName>
                        <assessmentType>Coursework</assessmentType>
                        <assessmentWeighting>40</assessmentWeighting>
                        <assessmentDueDate/>
                    </assessment>
                    <assessment>
                        <assessmentName>Test2</assessmentName>
                        <assessmentType>Coursework</assessmentType>
                        <assessmentWeighting>30</assessmentWeighting>
                        <assessmentDueDate/>
                    </assessment>
                </assessmentDetails>
            </module>
        </level4>
    </courseStructure>
</myCourse>
```

And I have created the two Entity classes:

Module.h

```
@interface Module : NSObject {

    NSString *moduleCode;
    NSString *moduleTitle;
    NSString *credits;
    NSString *semester;

}
```

AssessmentDetail.h

```
@interface AssessmentDetail : NSObject {

    NSString *assessmentName;
    NSString *assessmentType;
    NSString *assessmentWeighting;
    NSString *assessmentDueDate;

}
```

That's all I have really, I would like to be able to parse the XML data into an array to be implemented into a UITableView.

Can anyone guide me or help me with a simple way to actually have data output?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dou you really want to use NSXMLParser? If not, I suggest to use [TBXML](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html). It's really easy to use if you know the structure of your XML File. Start at this page to get the APIs: [TBXML APIs](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/API.html)

If you are familiar with Objective-c you'll get this XML parsed in half an hour. ;-)

Sandro Meier

Comment: Just tried it out, and it seems very good, thanks for the help, I'm finally getting somewhere now.

Comment: You're welcome! I had to do something familiar. For this tipe of tast TBXML is really the best thing...

Answer (score 0):

Why you can use a simple parser like [touchXml](http://foobarpig.com/iphone/touchxml-installation-guide.html)?

You can parse easily and set all of your variables / array to pass in your table.

Answer (score 0):

The very easy to use `NSXMLParser` is an event driven parser, meaning that as the parser goes through XML data it creates an event for each element the parser finds. These events are sent as messages to the delegate of the `NSXMLParser`. That delegate is a class you'll have to write that conforms to the `NSXMLParserDelegate` protocol.

To give an example for this XML data, the parser would send the delegate a `parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:` message upon finding `<assessmentName>`, then a `parser:foundCharacters:` message upon finding `Test1`, then a `parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:` upon finding `</assessmentName>`. Your delegate object should maintain state information. The `didStartElement` message should set the state to know that the next characters should be saved in a `AssessmentDetail` object's `assessmentName` ivar.

Your delegate need not implement all the methods in the `NSXMLParserDelegate` protocol. You could get away with just these three methods. The `didStartElement` element would need to know about ten elements, corresponding to your two data objects and their ivars, and change state appropriately, so that your `parser:foundCharacters:` method will put the data in the correct object.